# Retrieving ARFCN in a 5G NR NSA network

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to retrieve the ARFCN (Frequency Channel Number) that a device in a 5G network is currently using. The thing is that the 5G all the operators in my city offer is of the NSA type, thus meaning that the phone will always be registered to a 4G LTE network as a primary cell and will use a 5G NR cell as a secondary one.

To get the mentioned ARFCN one will normally use the [PhoneStateListener.onCellInfoChanged(List cellInfo)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener#onCellInfoChanged(java.util.List%3Candroid.telephony.CellInfo%3E)) method and check from the list which [CellInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellInfo) is that one the device is registered on, get the [CellIdentity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellIdentityNr) attached to it and then get the ARFCN. **The problem is that, aside from being only registerd to a CellInfoLTE (4G) there's no trace of any CellInfoNR (5G), registered or not.** Weird thing is I can get the 5G signal intensity through [PhoneStateListener.onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener#onSignalStrengthsChanged(android.telephony.SignalStrength)). The phone is always displaying the 5G logo on the top-right corner too.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In NSA mode, many operators show the 5G icon even though there is no 5G bearer in use, and only the 4G anchor cell is indicating that it supports 5G aggregation via upperLayerIndication.

So in your case you might not even have a 5G cell configured, and there is no way to force the phone to acquire a 5G bearer (it's up to the network to reconfigure you to the 5G cell). If you're not using mobile data, it is very that likely there is no 5G bearer in use.

But it is usually configured when you start a data session. So make sure to have a speedtest running, or some kind of download session when accessing CellIdentityNr/CellInfoNr.

The only API provided by Android Telephony to retrieve the NR-ARFCN is [`getNrarfcn()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellIdentityNr#getNrarfcn()).

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't answer sooner. I did a field test while streaming 4k video and still got nothing, and I got the same result using another apps on the Play Store like NetMonster, LTE Discovery or Cell Signal Monitor. Given that no further changes have been made to the Android API concerning 5G since I first started making this app, and the lack of other posts on the internet with the same concerns, I guess it is what it is, and that for the moment it is not possible to obtain the ARFCN.